# Symfony onKernetRequest detect which table

Tags: symfony, filter, doctrine

I have the following Listener in my code:

```
class BeforeRequestListener
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $em;
    /**
     * @var SessionInterface
     */
    private $session;

    /**
     * BeforeRequestListener constructor.
     * @param EntityManager $em
     * @param SessionInterface $session
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em,SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->session =$session;
    }

    /**
     * @param GetResponseEvent $event
     */
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event){
        //if() HERE
            $filter = $this->em->getFilters()
                ->enable(Utils::CLIENT_FILTER_NAME);
            $filter->setParameter(Utils::CLIENT_ID_NAME, $this->session->get(Utils::CLIENT_ID_NAME));       
    }
}
```

And this listener is made to enable some filter. i need to detect on which table/tables this is request id done so i can disable it when there is no column called `client_id` which is btw the `CLIENT_ID_NAME` const.

the reason is mentioned here : [Doctrine and symfony filter, debug the filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49894058/2724879)

i need to apply the filter only after a user logs in and some tables doesnt have the client_id field so i want to disable that check on these tables.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it (a bit dirty) not the way i wanted it but it works on the current db scale i have.

just added the following code to the `addFilterConstraint`

```
if(
    $targetEntity->getTableName() == 'table' ||
    $targetEntity->getTableName() == 'table2' ||
    $targetEntity->getTableName() == 'table3' ||
    $targetEntity->getTableName() == 'table4' ||
    $targetEntity->getTableName() == 'table5'
){
    return true;
}
return $targetTableAlias.'.'.Utils::CLIENT_ID_NAME.' = '. $this->getParameter(Utils::CLIENT_ID_NAME);
```

p.s in case someone got into this and noticed some strange behavior when using `return "";` just replace it with `return true;` sometimes it happens sometimes not i am still not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

If your request contains some information about tables, you can retrieve it like this:

```
$tables = $event->getRequest()->get('tables');
```

or you can assume affected entity/table by requested route:

```
$request = $event->getRequest();

// Matched route
$_route  = $request->attributes->get('_route');

// Matched controller
$_controller = $request->attributes->get('_controller');
```

By default Request object doesn't contain any information about table because it just passes some parameters to some action attached to some route, and the action interacts with some data model which presents some database table.

Comment: in this case assuming won't work xD, i want it to be verified data. also routing or controllers wont work sometimes its mixed

Comment: but if your request does not contain information about what entity it interacts, how can your code determine it?

Comment: shouldn't you move this check inside of the filter like it's done in doc https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/filters.html ? inside of filter you have access to `targetEntity` and `targetTableAlias`

Comment: talking about their docs, i found a bug in there. return ""; will destroy the app if the if condition was met. while return true will fix it. ;) just sayin. now back to your suggestion it will work if i had 2 or maybe 3 entities but when i have about 20 this will be a lot of ifs and i hat this. i think i found a way, working on it atm will post it if it worked

Comment: i voted up for the suggestion to make it as the docs, but as i said not what i really wanted xD

anyhow the $targetEntity in there had the getTableName which was somehow what i want;